# Plots with gnuplots is now working

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, errors, graphs, gnuplot

I've always used pgfplots to make my graphs, but I needed to do a graph for an implicit function, so I was consulting and I read about Gnuplots. I installed the program and compile my document, but the graph doesn't appear. Additionally, I have a set of points inside my graph. These points appear, but not the function.

I'm noob in LaTeX, so I hold that you can help me with this problem. This is an example of the problem and a part of my preamble, but I've tried with Overleaf and function appears, so I think that the problem is my configuration or TeXstudio

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{array}
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \caption*{\textbf{Curva de calibración}}
        \captionsetup{margin= 1.5cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[   
                xlabel=\textbf{{Concentración de Rojo de Fenol en $\mu M$}}, %xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, yshift=-10pt},
                ylabel= {\textbf{Absorbancia}}, %ylabel style={ at= {(ticklabel* cs:1.30)}},
                %axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
                axis lines=left,  % Dibuja solo ejes a la izquierda y abajo
                grid=both,
                xmin=0, xmax=14.5,
                ymin=0, ymax=13.5,
                width= 14cm, height= 10cm,
                ] \addplot[only marks, mark=*, 
                mark options={rojo, line width=0.01pt},
                %smooth,
                %blue,
                %thick
                ] plot coordinates {
                    (   0   ,   1.8 )
                    (   1   ,   1.6 )
                    (   2   ,   1.6 )
                    (   3   ,   1.7 )
                    (   4   ,   1.8 )
                    (   5   ,   1.8 )
                    (   6   ,   1.9 )
                    (   7   ,   2.0 )
                    (   8   ,   2.2 )
                    (   9   ,   2.4 )
                    (   10  ,   3.2 )
                    (   11  ,   11.4    )
                    (   12  ,   12.8    )
                    (   13  ,   13.0    )
                    (   14  ,   13.0    )
                };
                \addplot[only marks, mark=*, 
                mark options={blue, line width=0.01pt},
                %smooth,
                %blue,
                %thick
                ] plot coordinates {
                    (   0   ,   1.000   )
                    (   1   ,   1.087   )
                    (   2   ,   1.176   )
                    (   3   ,   1.269   )
                    (   4   ,   1.368   )
                    (   5   ,   1.477   )
                    (   6   ,   1.602   )
                    (   7   ,   1.753   )
                    (   8   ,   1.954   )
                    (   9   ,   2.279   )
                    (   10  ,   7.000   )
                    (   11  ,   11.678  )
                    (   12  ,   11.959  )
                    (   13  ,   12.115  )
                    (   14  ,   12.222  )
                };
                \draw[black, line width=1 pt] plot[id=curve, raw gnuplot] function{
                f(x, y) = x-y**2;
                set xrange [0:14.5];
                set yrange [0:13.5];
                set view 0,0;
                set isosample 600,600;
                set cont base;
                set cntrparam levels discrete 0;
                unset surface;
                splot f(x, y)
                };      
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{5pt}
        \caption{}
        \label{Curva de calibración}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! You don't have `\begin{document}` which will definitely cause an error on any system. You also lack `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` but i don't know if you just omitted those. You shouldn't use `H`.

Comment: You should also run `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` before `\addto\captionsspanish{...}`. Even more importantly, you need to deal with the `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/rojo' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.` error message and the `Package pgf Warning: Plot data file  'main.curve.table' not found. on input line 96.` warning message.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close the question because it is solved in the title `:)`